# Using Bootstrap Button Plugin in table to highlight multiple options

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap table with the bootstrap button plugin to make the columns clickable. This seems to work fine and as expected except for the fact that I want the first column in the `tbody` to be separate from the other 4 columns.

The `thead` section seems to work fine, I can click on a header and it'll highlight it as I expected it to do so.

The problem comes from the `tbody` section. I can click on the first column and it'll hightlight it but if I click on any of the 4 `td` columns it takes the selection off of the first column and highlights the new column I selected.

I am assuming that the bootstrap button plugin is not based off the inputs name but rather all in inputs it includes?

I built a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b721ncpg/1/) to help show what I am trying to describe. As you will see in the jsfiddle, I have **Option 4** selected in the `thead`, I also have **Option 3** and **Option 3-4** selected in the `tbody` however only **Option 3** is being highlighted by the bootstrap button plugin. And if you click on any of the options within the `tbody` it will only highlight that Option

Answer (score 0):

I will post the answer I figured out... I really hate using `setTimeout` but hey when it works why not.

This will provide a small delay in the user clicks on one of the options and then add the active class to all options that are currently checked.

```
$('#frmOptions .btn').on('click', function(event) {
    var $inputs = $('#frmOptions input[type="radio"]');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $inputs.each(function(index, input) {
            $(input).closest('.btn').toggleClass('active', $(input).is(':checked'));
        });
    }, 0.01);
});
```

you can see this working in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b721ncpg/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap allows only one child of an element with `data-toggle="button"` to be active at once. Therefore only one element in the table's `<tbody>` may be active at once.

The key part of the [Bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/button.js):

```
const rootElement = SelectorEngine.closest(
  this._element,
  Selector.DATA_TOGGLE
)

// ...

const activeElement = SelectorEngine.findOne(Selector.ACTIVE, rootElement)

if (activeElement) {
  activeElement.classList.remove(ClassName.ACTIVE)
}
```

An alternative approach would be to create a new table to represent the first "column".

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-3">
  <table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="button">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- empty placeholder -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <!-- first row header -->
      </tr>
      <!-- etc. -->
    </thead>
  <table>
</div>
<div class="col-9">
  <!-- the table you set up, minus the first column -->
</div>
</div>
```

The `.no-gutters` class helps the two tables *look* like one.

Complete solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/urbt6wcn/1/

[image: Table with three cells marked active]